# CodeIgniter 2.1.0: Accessing models within Models

Tags: php, class, codeigniter, model, codeigniter-2

I have four models in CodeIgniter for a forum I am building:

```
forum_model
category_model
user_model
subject_model
```

I wish to access the category, user and subject models within the forum model (ie: browse thread by user / category / subject) but they need to be independent for individual functions (ie: add user / subject / category)

Theres a lot more independent functions and basically what I was wondering was if it is bad practice to create a 'master' forum model (and what the best way to create the model would be) or if I should just do the linking in the controller?

I was thinking about setting the forum_model up like this:

```
class Forum_model extends CI_Model {
    function __construct() {
        parent::construct();
        $this->load->model('Category_model', 'category');
        $this->load->model('User_model', 'user');
        $this->load->model('Subject_model', 'subject');
    }
}
```

then possibly accessing the other models within methods using variable variables `$this->$model->method()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In 2.1.0, any property (i.e. model reference, library, etc.) not defined in a model's scope will magically access the CI super object:

```
<?php
function __get($key)
{
    return get_instance()->$key;
}
```

So, as long as you don't have `$category` `$user` or `$subject` member variables in your forum model, this should work.

*However*, usually it's good practice in MVC for models NOT to know about each other.  I'd caution you not to let your forum model function like a controller or a library (otherwise, it should be a controller or a library!).

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking the same thing and came up with the solution to use the model(s) functions in controller(s) and pass the result of the model functions to the `forum_model` if and when required!